# Source for: a permutation group is multiplicity-free if and only if its 2-orbits define an association scheme

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, characters, permutation-groups, association-schemes

I have recently proven the following (at least, so I believe):

> **Theorem.** Given a permutation group $\Sigma\subseteq\mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$ on the set $\Omega:=\{1,...,n\}$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. the permutation character of $\Sigma$  is multiplicity-free, that is, it decomposes into *distinct* irreducible characters.
> 2. the (self-paired) 2-orbits of $\Sigma$ (that is, its orbits on $\Omega\times \Omega$) define an [association scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_scheme).

I believe that this is known (if true). Has this result a name? Can someone point me to the literature proving/discussing/using this result? I am also grateful for a vague direction.

---

**Update**

As pointed out by Tom De Medts, an alternative formulation is the following:

> **Theorem.** Given a permutation group $\Sigma\subseteq\mathrm{Sym}(\Omega)$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. the permutation character of $\Sigma$  is multiplicity-free.
> 2. the association scheme formed by the 2-orbits of $\Sigma$ is commutative.

This claim can also be found in the beginning of Section 3 of [Commutative Association Schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.2475.pdf) by William J. Martin & Hajime Tanaka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed known, and can be found, for instance, in the book "Algebraic combinatorics. I. Association schemes" by Bannai and Ito (1984), Section II.2, Example 2.1 (p. 53).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I do not have access to the book right away, so let me ask: is this still true when the 2-orbits are not necessarily self-paired?

Comment: That is strange. On the one page available [here](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110630251-002/html), Example 2.3 states that the 2-orbits form an association scheme if $\Sigma$ acts transitively, no matter whether it is multiplicity-free. Isn't this in contradiction to what I claim in the question?

Comment: I assume that the difference lies in your definition of association scheme: Bannai and Ito consider not necessarily commutative association schemes, whereas other sources assume commutativity as part of the definition. Does this help?

Comment: I then wonder in which context my statement is supposed to be true according to the source you gave (unfortunately, I do still not have access to the book). Is this book assuming commutativity for this result?

Comment: In other words, should the theorem be: $\Sigma$ is multiplicity free if and only if the association scheme formed by the 2-orbits is *commutative*? I now use that the 2-orbits *always* form an association scheme.

Comment: @M.Winter My apologies for being somewhat imprecise. I have now included a screenshot of the relevant 2 half pages of the book. In particular, you can see how both conditions come into play: commutativity corresponds to the permutation character being multiplicity-free, whereas symmetry corresponds to the 2-orbits being self-paired.

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful!